# Custom ViewModel registration with Prism and MAUI - ViewModelLocationProvider the right way to do it?

Tags: maui, prism

We're migrating a Forms application, which uses Prism, to MAUI, and had a custom ViewModelLocator for one of our pages, implemented by overriding `ConfigureViewModelLocator` in App.xaml.cs.

With a Prism MAUI application, where do we now configure this?

I've tried using `ViewModelLocationProvider.Register` in .OnAppStart:

```
 ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(typeof(TestPage).ToString(),() =>
 {
     // Code to get the ViewModel here...
     return testPageViewModel;
 });
```

but the above code in the lambda is never getting called.

Is this the right place to do it? Do ViewModelLocationProvider registrations work under MAUI?

Answer (score 0):

See PrismAppBuilder.ConfigureViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver. You will receive your view's Type and are expected to return your view model's type. This needs to be added to your MauiProgram class inside of the UsePrism extension method handling.

Answer (score -2):

The registration of ViewModelLocationProvider should be done using Dependency Injection like below.

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>();
        
        // register the services, viewmodels or views here
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ViewModelLocationProvider>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Have a look at this example of implementing Dependency Injection: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiDependencyInjectionSample/tree/main

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question I'm asking. I've already got DI working, and my question is not related to registering the ViewModelLocator. In fact ViewModelLocator is static and doesn't need registration.

The question is regarding registering a custom method for resolving a ViewModel for a Page.